# Good algorithm to check if post frequency is spam

Tags: mysql, algorithm, frequency-analysis

I have a site where a people can post text. Each post is stored in a database with the ip of the poster and the time of the post. I want to be able to display a recaptcha if I can determine that the poster is a bot, spammer, etc.

What is a good algorithm to do this? The simplest choice is to analyze whether the number of posts in a pre-determined time period, say one minute, is greater than a chosen limit, say 10. However, this has the flaw of falling to multiple people posting from behind the same ip, or even a bot that creates random frequency intervals > the time period, or posts less than the limit in that time period.

Obviously there is no "correct" answer. Some algorithms are better than others however, and I am just trying to find the best one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a *limit*-based approach, and make good use of [website analytics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_analytics).

There must be limits to *how many times* an IP will post things in a single *context*. For example, for a StackExchange question (context), my IP address will (in most cases) post a single answer (not comments). Any more than one answer is uncommon, and hence, suspicious. In some other context, the frequency can be upto a few times, such as StackExchange comments.

Then there must be limits for time spent by a user in a single visit. If you are using <s>google</s> website analytics, you must be knowing the average time a user spends on your site. Make the time limit <s>a bit</s> considerably greater than that, or any other criteria you can come up with, including a hit and trial approach.

Also, you can use the [blogger](http://blogger.com/) approach, but with a minor change. Instead of having a captcha at each post, have it once the user logs in or makes the first post. After that, put  up a captcha only after some time interval or some number of posts by him/her.